# Replacing some old SKE 1/04 diodes for newer and quieter ones

Tags: diodes, rectifier

I´m working as a hobby on a early 80´s amplifier and it has SKE 1/04 diodes at the rectifier.

I pretend to make some upgrades, such as nichicon muse caps and I would also like to replace this 40 years old diodes with some newer and quieter ones.

Could anyone suggest a better option ?

Thank you all in advance.

[image: A simple rectifier circuit]

Comment: What makes you think the diodes are noisy?

Comment: In general, product recommendations are considered off-topic here.  If you can ask a specific question about the process of choosing a replacement, add it to the question.  It will help if you explain what the circuit requires of the new diodes.  Please also explain what kind of noise is being caused by the diodes.

Comment: Guys, there are better components for audio than others. If you don´t already know this, here is a nice sorce http://www.audiodesignguide.com/Ibridone/Sen_Semi_Diode_Apps-quik108.pdf

Comment: Not all "just suitable" components make the sound better. But, as always, if you don´t believe, that´s ok.

Answer (score 1):

The SKS-01/04 is only rated for 3500 uF while th[e SKE-02/04 i](https://www.pentod.com/userfiles/product_files_shared/SKE2.5.pdf)s rated for 5000 uF which is shown to be used.

The diodes might be hot but the caps make it noisy. Use good ones.  You might want to replace all the large e-Caps with better ones.

Comment: Thanks Tony, that´s something I have never considered (the capacitance for what th diode is rated)

Comment: But I still would like to receive tips of beter sounding components, like the SUF30 diodes.

Comment: SUF30 are obsolete and again Diodes don’t make audio HIFI sound noisy per se. it is the absence of good filter caps.

Comment: I would’ve thought the average silicon diode is ‘quieter’ due to the soft switching characteristics vs a fast ir ultra fast diode. Sounds like it is a crappy old 70’s amp. You can’t make a silk purse out if a sow’s ear.

Comment: The current pulse width  thru the diodes depends in % ripple voltage, so 10% ripple Voltage rises roughly  before the peak sine wave at 10x the average load current and then sags with the RC average load time constant. The diode size depends on C value maximum as surge energy  increases on startup and self heating from I^2Rd or 100 Iout^2*load , so a bigger cap causes less ripple hum but increase the current and heat rise by the square of peak current.